# Have a domain bring up a page hosted on another domain

Tags: dns

I need a domain--without hosting--to bring up content from another server. I.e. I have access to the domain's DNS, but nothing else.

How do I make a page--hosted on my server--load when my clients' URL shows up?

To clarify, I want a visitor:

1. To type sl.wellnessandyourself.com
2. For the page www.ceramiclion.com/drops/index.html to show up
3. For sl.wellnessandyourself.com to still be the url in the user's browser.

I've heard mixed comments on this. Websites like Weebly are able to do this. How can I do this as well?

Answer (score 0):

EDITED:

See the above comment about CNAME as a far better solution than what I just offered.

---

I am not fully certain, but I think the only way to really do this is to use an IFRAME tag embedded in your own page code:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>IFRAME Example</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <iframe style="min-width: 100%; min-height: 100%; outline: none;" src="http://www.ceramiclion.com/drops/index.html" />

  </body>
</html>
```

This sort of hearkens back to the good ole days of frames in HTML. Ahh, memories.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a CNAME? This is pretty much what it's used for. All you need is to edit the DNS records for the domain name. Obviously, you have to have access to these, but, it's pretty simple to do. No hosting required on your end.

You'll set up the CNAME for sl.wellnessandyourself.com to be www.ceramiclion.com/drops, and it should work how you want it.

Here is more information:

https://serverfault.com/questions/65712/using-cname-to-point-to-another-domain-to-save-ip-addresses

https://support.dnsimple.com/articles/cname-record/